# Validate a controlgroup with input of type="radio"

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate, jquery-mobile-fieldset, jquery-mobile-radio

I want to validate a form that have a controlgroup with inputs of `type="radio"` like this:

```
<form id="sendMessageFormContainer" action="#">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>To:</legend>
            <div id="messageToContainer">
                 <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="1" />
                 <label for="radio-choice-1">foo</label>
                 <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="2" />
                 <label for="radio-choice-2">bar</label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

//...

    <input id="sendMsgBtn" name="sendMsgBtnName" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I'm using `validate()` method to validate the rest of the elements, but I don't know which rule should I use to check that at least one radio button should be selected:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function () {

        $("#sendMessageFormContainer").validate({
            rules: {
                //???
            },
            messages: {
                //...
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert("Call Send Action");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

You need to add at least one class="required" to anyone of your radio inputs, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="1" class="required" />
<label for="radio-choice-1">foo</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="2" />
<label for="radio-choice-2">bar</label>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/a8cJA/

### Solution 2

Or you can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $("#sendMessageFormContainer").validate({
        rules : {
            "radio-choice-1" : { required : true }
        },
        messages : {
            "radio-choice-1" : "Please select radio button"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("Call Send Action");
        }
    });    
    $(document).on('click', '#sendMsgBtn', function(){ 
        $("#sendMessageFormContainer").validate().form();
    });    
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HwQeY/

Comment: Thank you! It works. But the message error isn't shown in red and below the fields... For instance, for the controlgroup it is shown above, and for input texts and textarea it appears inside, always black? Should I do some customization to get the errors message to show like this:http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/ ?

Comment: Problem with jQuery Mobile validation is its HTML structure after jQM restyle the HTML content. So error will not always show at the same place depending on a widget. Tell me where would you like it to show?

Comment: I would like to show the error message below the field, in red.

Comment: Then you would need to create your own customization, but be aware that it will take some playing with code to make it work right. Or do you want me to show you how to do it?

Comment: If you point me to some basic example it would be great. It can be an already existant example, just to understand how to do it...

Comment: Give me some time to test it here, every field is different in jQM form. I have a working example for select menu but it will not work here.